# Automatic update of the Database Engine (SQL Server) in a web-application context

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring

I'm working on a web application using Spring 3.0 and hibernate 3 with SQL Server 2008.

A specific work flow requires to check some data in the database periodically (each 1st of a month for example) and do some process (update some tables).

My question is, do I need to put a script on the server that will check continually the database? Or can I do this with SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[How to: Create a Job (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx), specifically,

[How to: Create a Transact-SQL Job Step (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)

and

[How to: Schedule a Job (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most flexible way will be to have an external script that runs at the desired times and does the updates.